# aiogram, дублирует сообщения без возможности успеть ответить на первое

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

```py
@disp.message_handler()
async def cartaker(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == '080':
        car = '080'
    elif message.text == 507 or message.text == '507':
        car = '507'
    elif message.text == 197 or message.text == '197':
        car = '197'
    await bot.send_message(chat_id = message.from_user.id, text = 'Сколько раз вы заправлялись: ')
    await UserState.toplivocount.set()


@disp.message_handler(state=UserState.toplivocount)
async def get_toplivoraz(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(toplivoraz=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()
    #await message.answer(f"Вы заправились: {data['toplivoraz']}")
    await state.finish()
    for i in range(int(data['toplivoraz'])):
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = message.from_user.id, text = 'Введите сумму заправки: ')
        await UserState.sumtoplivo.set()


@disp.message_handler(state=UserState.sumtoplivo)
async def get_toplivosumma(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(toplivosumma=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await state.finish()
```

Создал вопрос "Сколько раз вы заправлялись: " Дальше хочу создать цикл, чтобы по введеному кол-ву, бот запрашивал сумму каждого раза, когда машина заправлялась:

```py
for i in range(int(data['toplivoraz'])):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text='Введите сумму заправки: ')
    await UserState.sumtoplivo.set()
```

```py
@disp.message_handler(state=UserState.sumtoplivo)
async def get_toplivosumma(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(toplivosumma=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await state.finish()
```

Но когда ввожу сколько раз машина заправилась, например 2, выдает сразу 2 раза: Введите сумму заправки.

[image: Но когда ввожу сколько раз машина заправилась, например 2, выдает сразу 2 раза: Введите сумму заправки.]

Помогите пожалуйста.. Строго не судите я новичок

Comment: добавьте `if state.is_waiting_message:` условие для `async def get_toplivosumma`

Comment: не совсем понимаю что вы хотите сделать?
просто уберите цикл и ответьте один раз

Comment: хочу чтобы бот запрашивал кол-во раз заправки и позже в цикле суммировал сумму каждой заправки